# WCF MVC fields stay empty... why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

**Test**

```
public string username { get; set; }
public void Test(string test)
{
    this.username = test;
}
public string Get()
{
     return this.username   
}
```

**ITest**

```
[OperationContract]
public string Get();

[OperationContract]
public void Test(string test);
```

**TestProject**

```
var webapi3 = new v3.TestClient("BasicHttpBinding_IProductData1");
webapi3.Test("TestString");
var u = webapi3.Get();
```

**Problem**

Why does `u` remain empty, no mather what I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second call `Get()` will be potentially picked up on another thread.  You would need to make `username` static if you want state on the server.

You are communicating over HTTP, a stateless protocol.

There are other options than to make the field static, but this would at least get the test passing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a singleton instead of a static?

Comment: @TheunArbeider how would a singleton be better exactly?  The OP seems like test code so I'm assuming that thread sync is not the issue.  In a real scenario the state would be managed by a state store (like a database etc).

Answer (score 4):

`public void Test(string test)
{
    this.username = test; // test not username?
}`

Comment: Typo in my question. username is set to test but it still returns as empty

Comment: I think the problem must be that your service is stateless. This is good because stateful services may lead you into a whole realm of problems. However, if you must have state (again, I strongly advise against), try adding `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]` and `wsHttpBinding` binding.

Comment: Or as a more flexible stateful alternative, attach to a persistent datastore, and have callers provide a token on every call. This way you're not locked in to `wsHttpBinding`. There are probably other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume

```
public void Test(string test)
{
   this.username = username;
}
```

Should be:

```
public void Test(string test)
{
   this.username = test;
}
```

Comment: Typo in my question. username is set to test but it still returns as empty